# Can Logic App upload large files to blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, azure-storage-account

I've created an azure logic app that triggers (3 hours interval) when a new file is created in the OneDrive folder the action is to copy the file from the specific folder to the Azure storage account container. The app works perfectly while testing and sometimes it works fine.
The OneDrive folder contains large files (meeting recordings) that may be up to 1.5GB, not sure the size matters. Please advise, is there any other way to copy this file apart from the logic app to the storage account? or how to fix this issue.

Comment: If you’re getting an error, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment, and I have similar issue as below:

[image]

As One Drive connector in Standard Plan allows only 500 Mb of data that can be transferrable. Currently your requirement of 1.5Gb file transfer is not possible using Logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to copy it to Blob storage using a console application. It didnt worked with Logic App